# Is delete function is depreciated in HTML5 indexed database API

Tags: html, indexeddb

HI I am trying to delete a record in indexed database by passing its id, but my the function is not working properly and even Visual Studio intellisence is not showing any such function. Is objectstore.delete() function of the indexed database API has been depreciated or I am doing something wrong in calling it.

Following is the code spinet

```
  var result = objectStore.delete(key);
            result.onsuccess = function() {
                alert('Success');
            };
```

Comment: Glad to see that Deni answered your question! Help keep `indexeddb` tag healthy by selecting his answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete by key function is working fine in all browsers Chrome, FF and IE10. Here is the sample code:

```
var connection = indexedDB.open(dbName);
connection.onsuccess = function(e) {
    var database = e.target.result;
    var transaction = database.transaction(storeName, 'readwrite');
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
    var request = objectStore.delete(parseInt(key));
    request.onsuccess = function (event)
    {
        database.close();
    };

}
```

Comment: yes man I am doing the same thing on mozilla firfox 24.0, when i write the line  var request = objectStore.delete(key); it says expected identifier for the delete function and functionality doesn't work....

Comment: can you check that the type of key is number, if not try parsing the value before calling the function.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, I've added parsing to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything in IndexedDB works the same way, and your question belies a misunderstanding of this model: everything happens in a transaction.

Almost nothing is syncronous in the IndexedDB API except opening the database. So you'll never see anything like `database.delete()` or `database.set()` when dealing with records.

To delete a record, as with getting or setting, you start by creating a new transaction on the database. You then use that transaction (like in [Deni's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19117477/317937)) to invoke the method for your change.

The transaction then "disappears" when it goes out of scope of all functions and your change is then committed to the database. It's on this transaction's reference to the database (not the database itself) that you hook event listeners such as success and error callbacks.